# Covered Query Slow on 100 million+ Doc Collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would greatly appreciate any assistance with the following covered query:

```
db.searches.find({ $text: { $search: "dragon" }},{product_name:1,_id:0} ).limit(30)
```

The "searches" collection has 126 million documents and our goal is to achieve sub-second query performance.

The format of the collection is very simple:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("584b15d12bb299260a000006"),
"product_name" : "This is a product name",
"price" : 876
}
```

Both the index and the System Profile result are below. What we don't understand is why the stages are so slow -- total time is 161 seconds. As well, less common words (e.g. dog) are much faster than common words (e.g. dragon) which seems odd given that we're just asking for 30 documents.

This is running on MongoDB 3.4.0 with Wired Tiger. The indexes should be in-memory since they consume less than 50% of the 128GB of memory on the server.

INDEX

```
[
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "marketplaces.searches"
},
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_fts" : "text",
        "_ftsx" : 1,
        "price" : 1.0
    },
    "name" : "search_index_name_price",
    "ns" : "marketplaces.searches",
    "background" : true,
    "default_language" : "en",
    "language_override" : "en",
    "weights" : {
        "product_name" : 1
    },
    "textIndexVersion" : 3
}
]
```

SYSTEM PROFILE

```
{
"op" : "query",
"ns" : "marketplaces.searches",
"query" : {
    "find" : "searches",
    "filter" : {
        "$text" : {
            "$search" : "dragon"
        }
    },
    "limit" : 30.0,
    "singleBatch" : false,
    "projection" : {
        "product_name" : 1.0,
        "_id" : 0.0
    }
},
"keysExamined" : 1563505,
"docsExamined" : 1563505,
"cursorExhausted" : true,
"numYield" : 14547,
"locks" : {
    "Global" : {
        "acquireCount" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(29098)
        }
    },
    "Database" : {
        "acquireCount" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(14549)
        }
    },
    "Collection" : {
        "acquireCount" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(14549)
        }
    }
},
"nreturned" : 30,
"responseLength" : 4132,
"protocol" : "op_command",
"millis" : 161315,
"planSummary" : "IXSCAN { _fts: \"text\", _ftsx: 1, price: 1.0 }",
"execStats" : {
    "stage" : "LIMIT",
    "nReturned" : 30,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 145005,
    "works" : 1563538,
    "advanced" : 30,
    "needTime" : 1563507,
    "needYield" : 0,
    "saveState" : 14547,
    "restoreState" : 14547,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "invalidates" : 0,
    "limitAmount" : 30,
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "PROJECTION",
        "nReturned" : 30,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 144635,
        "works" : 1563537,
        "advanced" : 30,
        "needTime" : 1563507,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 14547,
        "restoreState" : 14547,
        "isEOF" : 0,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "transformBy" : {
            "product_name" : 1.0,
            "_id" : 0.0
        },
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "TEXT",
            "nReturned" : 30,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 144258,
            "works" : 1563537,
            "advanced" : 30,
            "needTime" : 1563507,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 14547,
            "restoreState" : 14547,
            "isEOF" : 0,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "indexPrefix" : {},
            "indexName" : "search_index_name_price",
            "parsedTextQuery" : {
                "terms" : [ 
                    "dragon"
                ],
                "negatedTerms" : [],
                "phrases" : [],
                "negatedPhrases" : []
            },
            "textIndexVersion" : 3,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "TEXT_MATCH",
                "nReturned" : 30,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 143819,
                "works" : 1563537,
                "advanced" : 30,
                "needTime" : 1563507,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 14547,
                "restoreState" : 14547,
                "isEOF" : 0,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "docsRejected" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "TEXT_OR",
                    "nReturned" : 30,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 143608,
                    "works" : 1563537,
                    "advanced" : 30,
                    "needTime" : 1563507,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 14547,
                    "restoreState" : 14547,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "docsExamined" : 1563505,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : 1563505,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 20499,
                        "works" : 1563506,
                        "advanced" : 1563505,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 14547,
                        "restoreState" : 14547,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "_fts" : "text",
                            "_ftsx" : 1,
                            "price" : 1.0
                        },
                        "indexName" : "search_index_name_price",
                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "backward",
                        "indexBounds" : {},
                        "keysExamined" : 1563505,
                        "seeks" : 1,
                        "dupsTested" : 1563505,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"ts" : ISODate("2017-04-28T14:34:57.320Z"),
"client" : "127.0.0.1",
"appName" : "MongoDB Shell",
"allUsers" : [],
"user" : ""
}
```

May consider Elasticsearch unless we can tune this further.

Comment: Are you sure you want `price` as an additional field in your text index? It would be interesting to compare the performance against a non-compound text index.

Comment: Instead of using a text index, how about storing all searchable values (e.g. "dragon", "dog") in an array field, and then use a multi-key index on the array?

Comment: @JohnnyHK  Thanks. That might speed the initial query but because the search can return up to 1M docs, it would be too slow to then search for the least expensive of those 1M docs.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks. Interesting idea. That is kind of how a text index is supposed to work so I would be a bit surprised if that was faster.

Comment: I also came across this, which shows that high-cardinality multikey indexes don't work well: http://codyaray.com/2014/11/mongo-multi-key-index-performance
Another effect may be if the multikey index is accessed in a random pattern instead of a mostly right-hand-side pattern (e.g. only recent timestamps queried)